# Does Google's algorithm look at a websites nameserver?

Tags: seo, google, pagerank, nameserver, google-algorithm

This might seem like a strange question but does Google's ranking algorithm look at what nameserver a website uses. For example, if it uses an enterprise dns provider does it rank higher?

I appear to have seen some evidence of this.

Comment: I doubt it. Google is mostly interested in (a) the content of your document and (b) who links to it and how.

Answer (score 2):

Google's algorithm is myth-ed to include things like name server IP and C class IP of the hosting, if you Google SEO C Class your see lots of hosting packages and articles offering this kind of information, some people swear by it when making vast linking networks and some people debate it....

This is because you could buy a reseller package on one hosting package, with 100 ip's with the [same C class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network), and same name server and setup 100 sites with 100 different domains linking to one site.. the only foot print left assuming that your not linking in patterns such as `A > B > B > A > C > E > F > A` would be the IP address of both the hosting and the servers.

So while my personally belief is that its very likely that Google does in fact use algorithms to detect linking networks as it would be silly not too, but its one factor of many and no way just the only factor. Your more likely to slip up with the pattern of linking and get caught.

And with this said down to the question you asked, it's unlikely that Google use DNS provider detection and reward more for CompanyA than CompanyB as their is little difference between provider and that what Google can detect.

Answer (score -2):

Google's algorithm Is Just Like Another Html Code.

**Google's algorithm does the work for you by searching out Web pages that contain the keywords you used to search**

**Changing Nameservers Will Typically Not Affect Your Rankings**
The simple act of changing nameservers will not make any changes to the search engine rankings or SEO factors.

Comment: The question wasn't about changing name servers so much as would using a higher quality name server be a signal to Google the site is higher quality and deserve to rank better. This answer misses the point of the question and is not useful.

Comment: **uses an enterprise DNS provider does it rank higher?*
I was Trying to Answer this Question.